# Prompt user for maps application

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

The Xamarin.Forms application I'm currently developing must send the user to a particular location, using any maps application he has installed.

I'd like to prompt the user to choose one of any maps application that he has installed (either native app - iOS Maps or Android Google Maps, or any other application, like Waze).

The `Device.OpenUri(new Uri(request));` works fine but it just opens the native app, without showing available apps.

Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: Bear in mind that some devices impose a 'forced default' pattern. If the user selects an application to become their default app for handling certain requests, it will not allow a prompt. I don't think you can force this.

Comment: You can write an Android dependacy service to get the package id that can open a url, but you can not do this on iOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way in iOS to get list of applications that displays map.

However you can display your own list of application that supports displaying map using `DisplayActionSheet()`

then you can show or hide an application from that list by checking if application is installed on users device or not.

In iOS this can be done by `CanOpenURL()`

see [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl).

**Example,**

To check if google maps is installed or not you can do

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(new NSUrl("comgooglemaps://"));
```

*to make it work you need to declare it in info.plist file like*

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
<string>comgooglemaps</string>
</array>
```